# X does not contain a definition for Y

Tags: c#

Question has been answered by ***csharpler***. I had no idea I created two of the same classes within each other (in the MenuMaker class)....

x

x

x

Here is the code sample I'm having trouble with:

```
namespace MeatMenuProgram
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MenuMaker menu = new MenuMaker() { Randomizer = new Random() };
            label1.Text = menu.GetMenuItem();
            label2.Text = menu.GetMenuItem();
            label3.Text = menu.GetMenuItem();
            label4.Text = menu.GetMenuItem();
            label5.Text = menu.GetMenuItem();
            label6.Text = menu.GetMenuItem();
        }
    }
}
```

I made a `MenuMaker` class:

```
namespace MeatMenuProgram
{
    class MenuMaker
    {
        class MenuMaker {

            public Random Randomizer;
            
            string[] Meats = { "Roast beef", "Salami", "Turkey", "Ham", "Pastrami" };
            
            string[] Condiments = { "yellow mustard", "brown mustard","honey mustard", "mayo", "relish", "french dressing" };
            
            string[] Breads = { "rye", "white", "wheat", "pumpernickel","italian bread", "a roll" };

                public string GetMenuItem() {
                    string randomMeat = Meats[Randomizer.Next(Meats.Length)];

                    string randomCondiment = Condiments[Randomizer.Next(Condiments.Length)];

                    string randomBread = Breads[Randomizer.Next(Breads.Length)];

                    return randomMeat + " with " + randomCondiment + " on " + randomBread;
                
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but it does not compile. The error log:

> Error  1   'MeatMenuProgram.MenuMaker' does not contain a definition for 'Randomizer'
>
> Error  2   'MeatMenuProgram.MenuMaker' does not contain a definition for 'GetMenuItem' and no extension method 'GetMenuItem' accepting a first argument of type 'MeatMenuProgram.MenuMaker' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: is `Randomizer` public?

Comment: Can you please show us your MenuMaker object?

Comment: Why is your MenuMaker class nested inside another MenuMaker class?

Comment: Is this a copy paste error? `class MenuMaker { class MenuMaker {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `MenuMaker`, as the error states, does not contain those properties/methods you are trying to access. You have to have

```
public string GetMenuItem() { }
public Random Randomizer { get; set; }
```

in the class `MenuMaker`.

You have the class MenuMaker nested in another one with the same name, you have to remove the doubled `class MenuMaker {` (and the closing brace at the end).

Comment: @user2129296 i updated my answer, let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb. I didn't notice the nested classes.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use the C# programming conventions, for example: start the names of variables, parameters and *fields* with a lower-case letter.

Then, take a *good hard look* at your code. Do you see a `MeatMenuProgram` namespace? Yes. Does it contain a `MenuMaker` class? Yes it does. Does *that class* contain a field `randomizer`? No... it does not. It contains *another class* also named `MenuMaker`. Instead, remove the inner class and all your problems go away:

```
namespace MeatMenuProgram
{
    class MenuMaker
    {
        public Random randomizer;

        string[] meats =
        { "Roast beef", "Salami", "Turkey", "Ham", "Pastrami" };

        string[] condiments =
        { "yellow mustard", "brown mustard","honey mustard" };

        string[] breads =
        { "rye", "white", "wheat", "pumpernickel" };

        public string GetMenuItem()
        {
            string randomMeat = meats[randomizer.Next(meats.Length)];
            string randomCondiment = condiments[randomizer.Next(condiments.Length)];
            string randomBread = breads[randomizer.Next(breads.Length)];

            return randomMeat + " with " + randomCondiment + " on " + randomBread;
        }
    }
}
```